# Error while installing Pandas and same kind of error while installing Datapane

Tags: python, pandas, pip, datapane

I am getting the following error when I try to install Pandas using pip install pandas. Python would install other modules correctly but not pandas and datapane. I am not sure what the error is saying, any help in fixing is appreciated.

```
Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Mariya Susnerwala\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r96h80d0\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython
>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'
"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'
AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AI
X'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (21 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.17.3
    Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, numpy
      Running setup.py install for numpy: started
      Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
      Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
      Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'done'
  ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"C:'

  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefi
x 'C:\Users\Mariya Susnerwala\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r96h80d0\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org
/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'
"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'
3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.
8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try installing it with pipwin.

```
pip install pipwin
```

then

```
pipwin install pandas
```